# $\sin \frac{1}{x} \neq \pm \frac{1}{x}$ for all real numbers $x$ excluding $0$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

**Question**: Prove that for all real numbers $x$ excluding $0$, $\sin(\dfrac{1}{x}) \neq \pm\dfrac{1}{x}$.

Here's what I've done so far:
Let $y = \dfrac{1}{x}$. Then $y\in (-\infty,0)\bigcup(0,\infty)$. We know that for $0 < y < \dfrac{\pi}{2}, -1<0<\cos y<\dfrac{\sin y}{y}<1 \Rightarrow -y<\sin y < y$. Since $\dfrac{\sin(-y)}{-y} = \dfrac{\sin y}{y}$ and $\cos(-y)=\cos y$, then for $-\dfrac{\pi}{2} < y<0, -1<0<\cos y<\dfrac{\sin y}{y} < 1 \Rightarrow -y>\sin y > y$. Since $\max(\sin y) = 1$ and $\min(\sin y) = -1 \forall y\in \mathbb{R}, y \in (-\infty,0)\bigcup(0,\infty)$, when $y>1$, $\sin y \neq y\wedge \sin y \neq -y$ (notice that if we let $y < -1,$ we will obtain an equivalent expression). So, considering all cases, $\sin y \neq y, -y \forall y\in \mathbb{R}, y \in (-\infty,0)\bigcup(0,\infty)$. Since $y= \dfrac{1}{x},$ then $sin(\dfrac{1}{x})\neq \dfrac{1}{x} \forall x\in \mathbb{R}, x\neq 0$

Edit: I don't know if it's the work above that makes this question confusing, but I'll delete my "work" if need be. It should be **very** obvious as to what the question is.

Comment: What makes you think this is true? I would expect an infinite number of solutions to $\sin x = \pm\dfrac1x$.  For example $x \approx \pm 1.11415714087\ldots$ or $x \approx \pm  2.772604708\ldots$ or $x \approx \pm 3.4368289123\ldots$

Comment: Please use `$\sin x$` for $\sin x$.

Comment: You have $\sin{x}$ in the title and $\sin(1/x)$ in the body of the question.

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity.  Obviously the equation $\sin(x)=\frac 1x$ has solutions.  If you meant something else, please write it out clearly.  If you meant $\sin \left(\frac 1x\right)=\pm \frac 1x$...then what's the point of writing the reciprocals?  Just write $\sin(x)=\pm x $ for $x\neq 0$.

Comment: @lulu sorry I was in a rush to type up the question so that's why I made the typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proving that $\sin(\frac{1}{x})\neq \pm\frac{1}{x}\forall x\neq 0$ is same as saying that the only possible solutions of $y=\pm\sin y$ are at $0$, which is true, because the functions $y-\sin y$ and $y+\sin y$ are non-decreasing on $\mathbb R$ (that you can check by differentiation) and therefore intersect $x$-axis only once.

Answer (score 1):

The  function $$y=\sin t$$ and functions  $$y= \pm t$$ intersect only at $t=0$

Let $t= 1/x$ and the result is $$\sin( 1/x) = \pm  1/x$$ do not have any  real solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a geometric proof that $\sin\theta\neq\theta$ for $0<\theta<\frac\pi2 $ (measured in radians, of course).

[image]

Consider an angle of measure $\theta$ centered on the unit circle.  $CD=\sin\theta$ and the length of arc $CB$ is $\theta$.  Since the unique shortest path from a point to a line is the perpendicular line segment from the point to the line, we conclude that $\sin\theta<\theta$.

The proofs considering the functions are stronger because they consider the entire domain of $x\neq0$, but perhaps this gives you a visual intuition of why it would be true near zero.